# System GMM Estimator

Tags: econometrics, paneldata

Consider the dynamic linear model given by:
\begin{equation}
y_{it} = \rho y_{i,t-1} + \alpha_i + \nu_{it}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_i$ represents individual fixed effects. The GMM two-step estimator imposes $0.5(T-1)(T-2)$ moment restrictions, specifically:
\begin{equation}
E[y_{i,t-s} \Delta \nu_{it}] = 0
\end{equation}
for $t=3,\ldots,T$ and $s \ge 2$.

The System-GMM estimator (Bundell and Bond, 1998) extends these moment restrictions beyond the first differenced equations to also include the levels equation. This is achieved by assuming a mild stationarity assumption on the series $y_{it}$. Can you provide insight into how imposing a mild stationarity assumption on the series ensures the validity of the following moment restrictions:
\begin{equation}
E[\Delta y_{i,t-1} (\alpha_i + \nu_{it})] = 0
\end{equation}
for $t=3,\ldots,T$

Comment: If you do not get an answer here in, say, a week, you may consider posting the question on Cross Validated Stack Exchange. (Posting on multiple Stack Exchange sites simultaneously is frowned up, so I would wait a week.)

Comment: A simple intuition is that when $y_{it}$ is mean stationary, $\Delta y_{it}$ (and thus $\Delta y_{i,t-1}$) is uncorrelated with $\alpha_i$. Also $\Delta y_{i,t-1}$ is uncorrelated with $v_{it}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exploit additional non-redundant moment conditions for the equations in levels by imposing the following initial condition assumption:
\begin{equation}
    E[\Delta y_{i2} \alpha_i] = 0
\end{equation}
This assumption requires a mean stationarity restriction on the initial conditions $y_{i1}$.

Recall the concept of a mean stationary series: $x_{it}$ is stationary in mean if $E[x_{it}] = E[x_{is}] = \mu < \infty$, where the first moment is time-independent and finite.

Now, take the expected value of $y_{it}$ conditioned on $\alpha_i$. Due to mean stationarity,
\begin{equation}
    E[y_{it}|\alpha_i] = \rho E[y_{it}|\alpha_i] + \alpha_i
\end{equation}
Eventually,
\begin{equation}
    E[y_{it}|\alpha_i] = \frac{\alpha_i}{1-\rho},
\end{equation}
and this is the steady-state value of $y_{it}$, where the series converges for the individual $i$.

Now, exploiting the restriction on the initial conditions process generating $y_{i1}$, I write $y_{i1}$ as
\begin{equation}
    y_{i1} = \frac{\alpha_i}{1-\rho} + e_{i1}
\end{equation}
with $e_{i1}$ being an i.i.d. innovation.

Considering your DGP for the first period observed (at $t=2$):
\begin{equation}
    y_{i2} = \rho y_{i1} + \alpha_i + \nu_{it}
\end{equation}

Subtracting $y_{i1}$ from both sides of this equation:
\begin{equation}
    \Delta y_{i2} = (\rho - 1) y_{i1} + \alpha_i + \nu_{i2}
\end{equation}
and using the expression for $y_{i1}$:
\begin{equation}
    \Delta y_{i2} = (\rho - 1) \left(\frac{\alpha_i}{1-\rho}+ e_{i1}\right) + \alpha_i + \nu_{i2}
\end{equation}
And,
\begin{equation}
    \Delta y_{i2} = (\rho - 1) e_{i1} + \nu_{i2}
\end{equation}

Thus, you see that this moment condition is equivalent to the first one:
\begin{equation}
    E[\Delta y_{i2} \alpha_i] = E\{ [(\rho - 1) e_{i1} + \nu_{i2}]\alpha_i \} = 0
\end{equation}

Since, in defining the DGP, you assumed that the innovations $\nu_{it}$ are uncorrelated with the individual effects, the moment condition holds if $E[e_{i1} \alpha_i] = 0$.

Indeed, assuming $E[\Delta y_{i2} \alpha_i] = 0$, given the AR(1) structure, we have $E[\Delta y_{is} \alpha_i] = 0$, for $s = 2, \ldots, T$. To see this:
\begin{equation}
    \Delta y_{it} = \rho \Delta y_{i,t-1} + \Delta \nu_{it} = \rho [\alpha \Delta y_{i,t-2} + \Delta \nu_{i,t-1}] + \Delta \nu_{it}
    = \rho^2 \Delta y_{i,t-2} + \Delta \nu_{it} + \rho \Delta \nu_{i,t-1}
\end{equation}

Generalizing,
\begin{equation}
    = \rho^{t-2} \Delta y_{i2} + \sum_{s=0}^{t-3} \rho^s \Delta \nu_{i,t-s}
\end{equation}
for $t = 3, \ldots, T$. This implies an additional $T - 2$ non-redundant linear moment conditions for the equations in levels, which can be written as
\begin{equation}
    E[ \Delta y_{i,t-1} (\alpha_i +\nu_{it})] = 0 \quad \text{for } t = 3, \ldots, T 
\end{equation}

**Intuition:**
The mean stationarity assumption suggests that individual entities indexed by $i$ can temporarily deviate from their respective steady states. However, these deviations are not systematic, and over the long run, the series tends to converge back to its steady state $\frac{\alpha_i}{1-\rho}$. For example, a positive fixed effect alone consistently boosts $y$ in each period, akin to how investment bolsters the capital stock. However, under the assumption that $|\rho| < 1$, this incremental effect (under stationarity) is offset by reversion to the mean in the long run.

The additional moment conditions from Blundell and Bond(1998):
\begin{equation}
    E[(\alpha_i +\nu_{it}) \Delta y_{i,t-1} ] = 0 \quad \text{for } t = 3, \ldots, T 
\end{equation}

can be rewritten as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    E\left[ (\alpha_i + \nu_{it})(y_{it-1} - y_{it-2}) \right] &= E\left[ (\alpha_i + \nu_{it})(\rho y_{it-2} + \alpha_i + \nu_{it-1} - y_{it-2}) \right] \\
    &= E\left[ (\alpha_i + \nu_{it})((\rho - 1)y_{it-2} + \alpha_i + \nu_{it-1}) \right] \\
    &= E\left[ \alpha_i((\rho - 1)y_{it-2} + \alpha_i) \right] \\
    &= 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

which is equivalent to:
\begin{equation}
E\left[ \alpha_i((\rho - 1)y_{it} + \alpha_i) \right]  \quad \text{for } t \ge 1
\end{equation}

By dividing this condition by $(1-\rho)$:

\begin{equation}
E\left[ \alpha_i \left( y_{it} -  \frac{\alpha_i}{1-\rho} \right) \right] = 0
\end{equation}

Deviations from long-run means must not be correlated with the fixed effects (due to the stationarity hypothesis). If $E\left[ \alpha_i \left( y_{it} -  \frac{\alpha_i}{1-\rho} \right) \right] = 0$ holds in $ t$, then it also holds in all subsequent periods. Effectively, this is a condition on the initial observation.

Comment: What I'm still missing is why mean stationarity is necessary to make the additional Bundell and Bond moment conditions to hold

Comment: Now, the concept should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Without stationarity, the moment condition is not valid. We can consider the case where $\rho=1$. Then $\Delta y_{it}=\alpha_i + \nu_{it} $ and
$$ E[\Delta y_{i,t-1} (\alpha_i + \nu_{it})] = E[ (\alpha_i + \nu_{i,t-1}) (\alpha_i + \nu_{it})],$$
which is nonnegative if $\nu_{it}$ is not correlated with $(\alpha_i,\nu_{i,t-1})$.

**EDIT**: With mean stationarity, as defined in Tony's post, it follows that $E[y_{it}|\alpha_i] = \rho E[y_{i,t-1}|\alpha_i] + \alpha_i,$ and so,
$$ \Delta E[ y_{i,t-1} | \alpha_i ] = \rho \Delta E[ y_{i,t-2} | \alpha_i )] = 0, $$
hence $ E[ \Delta y_{i,t-1} \alpha_i ] = 0$. If in addition $ E[ \Delta y_{i,t-1} \nu_{i,t} ] = 0,$ then $$ E[ \Delta y_{i,t-1} ( \alpha_i+\nu_{i,t} ) ] = 0. $$

Comment: What do you mean? We know that $y_{i,t-1} = \rho y_{i,t-2} + \alpha_i + \nu_{t,-1}$, why does the term $y_{i,t-2}$ vanish in $E[\cdot]$ for $\rho=1$?

Comment: @Rebecca: If $\rho=1$, your first equation yields $y_{it} = y_{i,t-1} + \alpha_i + \nu_{it}$ or in other words $\Delta y_{i,t} = y_{it} - y_{i,t-1} = \alpha_i + \nu_{it},$ and 
$\Delta y_{i,t-1} = \alpha_i + \nu_{i,t-1}.$

Comment: Right, it was trivial. However, my confusion lies in understanding why, when $|\rho| < 1$, the moment condition holds. To illustrate this, consider  $y_{it} - y_{i,t-1} = (\rho - 1)y_{i,t-1} + \alpha_i + \nu_{it}$. Lagging by one period, the covariance in population with $(\alpha_i + \nu_{i,t})$ reads: $E[((\rho - 1)y_{i,t-2} + \alpha_i + \nu_{i,t-1})(\alpha_i + \nu_{i,t-1})]$. Could you explain why this expectation is expected to be zero when $|\rho| < 1$?

Comment: @Rebecca: see the edit.

Comment: But, the expectation of $y_{i,t-1}$ conditioned on $\alpha_i$ is not zero,  as pointed out by Tony. I also do not get how you can move the difference operator outsitde the $E[\cdot]$ term

Comment: @Rebecca: Because the expectation is linear, $ \Delta E[ y_{i,t-1} | \alpha_i ] = E[ y_{i,t-1} | \alpha_i ] - E[ y_{i,t-2} | \alpha_i ]= E[ y_{i,t-1} - y_{i,t-2} | \alpha_i ] = E[ \Delta y_{i,t-1} | \alpha_i ].$ This term is null under mean stationarity.